# String resource not accessable in manifest during building process

Tags: android, git, twitter-fabric

To avoid my API keys from getting committed on source control (git) I have made an XML resource file called `api_keys.xml` under the `values` directory. This file is listed under `.gitignore`.

I access these string resources the usual way by using `@string/..` or `.getString(R.string...)`. This approach works everywhere but in the `manifest.xml` file.

I have fabric set-up and in the `manifest` file this is how I try to pass the key -

```
<meta-data
 android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
 android:value="@string/FABRIC_API_KEY" />
```

But, when I try to build the APK I get the following error -

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug'.
>   Crashlytics Developer Tools error.

This error goes away if I replace `@string/FABRIC_API_KEY` with the actual key.

Is there a way I can fix this? Or any other approach I can use to prevent my API keys form getting published on the source control.

Comment: Are you sure, that FABRIC_API_KEY is in your correct folder? Because it should work even if it isn't in the main values/strings.xml.

Comment: @gabodroid Yes! It is under `values` which has the other xml files in it too. Also, I access the other API key programmatically in a class without any problem.